# How to respect 80-character limit per line of text in source code

Tags: formatting, line-breaking

Suppose I have a long line of *italicized* text in a report or other document. If it is more than 80 characters long, I may want to move everything after the 79th column position to the next line in source code. But I don't want this to have any effect on the way the text is rendered (i.e. still just as one single italicized line).

Is there a TeX command available as a line terminator that says to just pick up at the next source code line as though it was the same line?

In my case, I am describing an experience in an `itemize` block:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Describe some stuff that happened here and it is a long description that should be stopped at character 80 and continued on the next line, but can easily fit on a single line in the rendered document.}
\end{itemize}
```

If I manually restructure the source myself, it rendered with linebreaks at the places where I move the text to the next line:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{Describe some stuff that happened here and it is a long 
      description that should be stopped at character 80 and continued on 
      the next line, but can easily fit on a single line in the rendered 
      document.}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Are you talking about an editor tool? For TeX it is the same, if you leave an empty line then you'll get a new paragraph but if you simple change the line the result is the same. So your two codes above are different only into the editor. They have the same output.

Comment: No it is not an editor thing. I see different rendered outputs merely by hitting return to migrate some of the text to the immediately following line of the source code. No extra empty lines, etc. Just splitting text onto two adjacent lines creates two adjacent lines in the output. I've been using TeX for about 10 years now and had never encountered this. I'll try to provide a minimum working example with different document content.

Comment: Sorry, it is within a `textit{...}` block if that makes a difference. The `textit` stuff is more than 80 characters and so the opening `{` is on one line, but the closing `}` is on the next line.

Comment: Put `%` as the last character on the line (the 79th) and then TeX will not see the line break as a space. I've never seen a line break rendered as a line break, though. Unless in a verbatim environment or whatever.

Comment: I would suspect that `\obeylines` is in effect, from something a bit higher up the source file.

Comment: Please make a _complete_ example document that shows the effect, what you describe is _not_ the default behaviour, end of line acts as a space normally (or two consecutive ends of lines act as \par)

Comment: If you are adding a linebreak to the middle of commented text, the text following the newly inserted linebreak will no longer be a comment.  Example: `%This is my code` to `%This is<linebreak> my code` will make `my code` part of the text, no longer a comment.